# JS native format date method

Tags: javascript

I've got trivial question for which I can't find simple answer - how can I format Date object in order to get it in format I need? For example, "20.01.2014". I know about moment.js library but I must do it using only native JS. Please, give me answer. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) will help?

Answer (score 0):

You use the [`getHours`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.gethours), [`getMinutes`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.getminutes), and [`getSeconds`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.getseconds) (or [`getUTCHours`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.getutchours), [`getUTCMinutes`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.getutcminutes), and [`getUTCSeconds`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.getutcseconds)) methods on your `Date` instance, which give you numbers, and then do the formatting with string manipulation.